# How to make UIProgressView with many color in circle with one bar in Swift?

Tags: swift, rounding, uiprogressview

I tried to find how to make cicle not line in circle border in Swift like this [image]

Can someoen can give me a some tips to make this with round at end like this.

Comment: Ask not what `UIProgressView` can do for you.  Ask what you can do for `UIBezierPath` and `CGLineCap`.

Comment: Add `CAShapeLayer` to the list as well.